# Jackson - configure override for collections via Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I am customizing treatment of collections in my Jackson's object mapper in my Spring Boot config by constructing a new mapper like so

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Autowired(required = true)
public void objectMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {

    mapper.configOverride(Collection.class).setInclude(JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY, null));
    mapper.configOverride(List.class).setInclude(JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY, null));
    mapper.configOverride(Map.class).setInclude(JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY, null));

}
```

While this works, I understand that a more elegant approach is to use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` :

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizeJackson2ObjectMapper() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            builder
            .indentOutput(true)
            .someOtherMethod(...)

        }
    };
}
```

How do I implement ObjectMapper collection tweaks above via Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `Module` defined locally, like in [this other use case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48984704/1350869). The `SetupContext` also has a `configOverride()` method, just like the `ObjectMapper` itself.

Comment: I cannot mark the topic as solved but it works perfectly. Thx

Answer (score 0):

No idea ? I'm interested to do the same just to add :

```
mapper.configOverride(Map.Entry.class).setFormat(forShape(Shape.OBJECT));
```

Because `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` doesn't work well ( https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1419 ) and but after Jackson 2.5 it is the only solution (but requires 2.9.x) to restore the previous behavior without writing a custom serializer.