# Configure a Jackson's DeserializationProblemHandler in Spring environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

As I understood, Spring is already providing a bean for Jackson `ObjectMapper`. Therefore, instead of creating a new bean, I'm trying to customize this bean.

From this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring), and then this [Github project](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-jackson-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/demo/Application.java) I used `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean to achieve this customization.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder(ApplicationContext context) {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.findModulesViaServiceLoader(true);
    return builder;
}
```

Then, I was trying to customize the deserializer in order to make it lenient: if an exception is raised when deserializing a property, I want the result object's property to be `null` and let the deserialization continue (default is to fail on first property that cannot be deserialized).

I've been able to achieve that with a class `NullableFieldsDeserializationProblemHandler` that extends `DeserializationProblemHandler` (I do not think the code is relevant but if needed, I can share it).

The simplest way to register this handler is to use the `.addHandler()` method of `ObjectMapper`. But of course, doing like this, I would need to set that every time I inject and use the `ObjectMapper`. I'd like to be able to configure handler so that every time the `ObjectMapper` is auto-wired, the handler is already present.

The best solution I came up with so far is to use a `@PostConstruct` annotation only to register the problem handler.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration implements InitializingBean {

  @Autowired private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Bean
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder(ApplicationContext context) {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.findModulesViaServiceLoader(true);
    return builder;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    objectMapper.addHandler(new NullableFieldsDeserializationProblemHandler());
  }
}
```

But the problem of this solution is that it seems I can still access an autowired `ObjectMapper` that doesn't have yet registered the problem handler (I can see it happening after when I need it in debug mode).

Any idea how I should register this handler? I've noticed `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` has a `.handlerInstantiator()` but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

**Note** I've also tried with [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer.html) since I'm using Spring Boot but had no better results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to directly add a `DeserializationProblemHandler` to the `ObjectMapper` via a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` or `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`. The `handlerInstanciator()` method is for something else.

However, it's possible to do so by registering a Jackson module:

- the builder has a `modules()` method
- the module has access via `setupModule()` to a `SetupContext` instance, which has a `addDeserializationProblemHandler()` method

This works:

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizer() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            builder.modules(new MyModule());
        }
    };
}

private static class MyModule extends SimpleModule {
    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        // Required, as documented in the Javadoc of SimpleModule
        super.setupModule(context);
        context.addDeserializationProblemHandler(new NullableFieldsDeserializationProblemHandler());
    } 
}
```

Comment: It does do the trick also I'm not sure what would happen if I had to register multiple modules. Should I register the problem handler on each of them? And then what about the ones that are automatically register via `findModulesViaServiceLoader(true)`? Well, it raises some more questions but for the original question, I consider it solved. Thank you :-)

Comment: Modules are a way to configure a common `ObjectMapper`, which is where the `DeserializationProblemHandler` ends up : the `SetupContext` is a wrapper around the `ObjectMapper`, _not_ the `Module`. So there's no problem with multiple modules, as long as they don't try to set up different handlers (they usually don't anyway).

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem, by the way :)

Comment: Hi I tried this solution but the code flow is not coming inside `handleUnknownProperty`. I am using the code provided in this answer. Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 1):

What about writing a bean like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // jackson 1.9 and before
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); 
        // or jackson 2.0
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

This is for global configuration. If, instead, what you want to do is to configure the feature for specific a class, use this annotation above the class definition:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Comment: Well, the whole point of _customizing_ the bean is about customizing, not create a new one. I'd like to customize the instance of Spring in order to get all modifications/customizations that Spring already did on the `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: This is `one instance` that Spring wil initialize once and use throughout the application.

Comment: Yes sure, it’s a bean. My point is, Spring already provide this bean. If I create one, I will end up with two and Spring might randomly choose one. Also, the one already provided might already be initialized and/or customized and I’d like to keep these customizations.