# Customizing the exception thrown by jackson bind on GAE standard

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jackson, jackson-databind

I've been searching to find a way to customise exception thrown by `Jackson` bind on `GAE`.

The problem is that when I sent a string parameter where `API` method expects `Integer` throws a `Jackson`'s `InvalidFormatException`. I want to customize the message thrown by the exception but I couldn't find a way. Please help with this.

For e.g:

```
@Api(
name = "echo",
version = "v1",
namespace =
@ApiNamespace(
    ownerDomain = "echo.example.com",
    ownerName = "echo.example.com",
    packagePath = ""
),
issuers = {
    @ApiIssuer(
        name = "firebase",
        issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/YOUR-PROJECT-ID",
        jwksUri =
            "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system"
                + ".gserviceaccount.com"
    )
})

public class Echo {
   @ApiMethod(name = "echo")
   public Message echo(Message message, @Named("n") @Nullable Integer n) {
      return doEcho(message, n);
   }    
}
```

In the above code if the echo endpoint is hit with payload

[image]

then the response is

[image]

In this case is it possible to throw a custom exception or customize the message

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to register [`DeserializationProblemHandler`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/DeserializationProblemHandler.html)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
    @Override
    public Object handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext ctxt, Class<?> targetType, String valueToConvert, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Handle parse problem for value = " + valueToConvert);
        throw new CanNotParseJsonException("Can not deserialise " + valueToConvert, null);
    }
});
```

Your exception should extend `JsonMappingException` in other case it will be wrapped. Example exception:

```
class CanNotParseJsonException extends JsonMappingException {

    public CanNotParseJsonException(String msg, Throwable problem) {
        super(null, msg, problem);
    }
}
```

See:

1. [Configure a Jackson's DeserializationProblemHandler in Spring environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773728/configure-a-jacksons-deserializationproblemhandler-in-spring-environment)
2. [Can't set ProblemHandler to ObjectMapper in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644099/cant-set-problemhandler-to-objectmapper-in-spring-boot)
3. [Java Source](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/DeserializationProblemHandler.java)

Comment: I got the point what you are suggesting but my application is not Spring Boot based

Comment: You do not need to have `Spring Boot` to make it work. You just need to configure `ObjectMapper` instance and it should work. I linked to some examples where `Spring Boot` is used but it is not required.

Comment: Ziober,I tried using Guice to configure it still it is not working `@Provides  ObjectMapper ObjectMapperProvider() { ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT); mapper.addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
            @Override public Object handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext ctxt, Class<?> targetType, String valueToConvert, String failureMsg) throws IOException { throw new JacksonBindingException("Can not deserialise " + valueToConvert, null);
          }}); return mapper;}` . I added this code in Guice module

Comment: @Chaturasan, You need to be sure `Guice` uses this `ObjectMapper` which you have configured and for which created `ObjectMapperProvider` factory method.