# Custom Message when unknown field when quarkus-resteasy-jackson mapping

Tags: jackson, quarkus

I want to set custom error Message for Unrecognized field and others errors with request body.
I tried ExceptionMapper but it dont work :/
Using quarkus and Jackson

```
public class ReqDTO {
    private String a;
}
```

when send request:

```
{
    "a": "a"
}
```

its look good. But when send:

```
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
}
```

have error response:

```
Unrecognized field "b"; (class ReqDTO), not marked as ignorable
```

Want customize this message and other bad json body (like too much fields) to own message like "BAD_JSON_SCHEMA".

Tried

```
@Provider
public class ExHandler implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException>{

    public Respone toResponse(JsonMappingException e) { 
        //response bad field impl
    }
}
```

But its not work. Looks like a json handle exception faster. Tried with "Exception", "JsonParseException" but nothing changed :/

```
@Path("/")
public class Controller {
    @Post
    @Consume(APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getA(@Valid ReqDTO reqDTO){
        //logic
    }
}
```

@Edit

Found something like DeserializationProblemHandler but dont know how change message for handleUnknownProperty :/

Comment: What have you done so far? It would be great to show some code samples, so others can reproduce the issues you have.

Comment: You can try registering a simple module with the proper handler. An example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773728/configure-a-jacksons-deserializationproblemhandler-in-spring-environment . This is spring configuration though, you have to modify it for quarkus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Singleton
RegisterCustomModuleCustomizer implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {

    public void customize(ObjectMapper mapper){
        mapper.addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler(){
            @SneakyThrows
            @Override
            public boolean handleUnknownProperty(...... params){
                throw new ApplicationException("ERRO_BODY_MESS");
            }
        }
    }
}

@Provider
public class ExHandler implements ExceptionMapper<ApplicationException>{

    public Respone toResponse(ApplicationException ex) { 
        return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```